# Why redirection operators from windows prompt create text ignoring line break?

Tags: windows, java, prompt, notepad, linebreaks

I tried to output to a text file using redirection operators `> and >>` from a java class but it ignores line feed `\n` from java when the *.txt* file is opened with the **Notepad** from windows 10. It's interesting because on the *prompt* the line feed works just fine and if I use `System.out.println("")` it works normally in the **Notepad**.

Class with `\n` line feed:

```
class n{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.print("This\n");
        System.out.print("Should\n");
        System.out.print("Be\n");
        System.out.print("Separated.\n");


    }

}
```

Class using `System.out.println("")`:

```
class ln{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("This");
        System.out.println("Should");
        System.out.println("Be");
        System.out.println("Separated.");

    }

}
```

Output in the *prompt*:

[image: Prompt]

Output in text file from *class n* (*n.txt*) opened with **Notepad**:

```
ThisShouldBeSeparated.
```

Output in text file from *class ln* (*ln.txt*) opened with **Notepad**:

```
This
Should
Be
Separated.
```

These two above should be equal.

I tested with the *class n* **public** but it didn't change the result.

I've searched and found about how to `echo` a line feed, that's not what I want, I want the redirected text file working like the *prompt*.

One interesting detail is when I paste the text from *n.txt* in here (*writing a question*), in the *Microsoft Word*, *Notepad++* or *WordPad* (*or open the file in the programs cited*) it "fixed" the error and was equal the result from *class ln*.

**EDIT**

I think it's not a duplicate because when I wrote the question I didn't even think about the possible *Notepad* problem. The title is completely different so I answered my own question for people who didn't think that the problem is the *Notepad*, like me before, may get an good solution.

If I'm wrong I would be happy to be corrected.

Comment: I posted the Q&A even though I discovered the solution while writing the question because at first I didn't even wrote that was using _Notepad_ because I was sure that the problem was in the _prompt_. So I think others can have the same problems and dificulty to find the solution to this.

Comment: Questions about Java programming problems are off-topic for SU, and the problem of "my text file doesn't show line breaks in Notepad" has already been covered (as you've pointed out).  Voting to close.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I maintain the Q&A because I wasn't thinking about the possibly problem in the _Notepad_ and I think other people could think the problem is in the _prompt_ and not in the _Notepad_ like myself before. If this isn't enough to differentiate this question to the "_Notepad_ ignoring linebreaks" than I will be glad to delete it.

Comment: You're right, duplicate questions with sufficient difference in phrasing can be helpful in pointing people to the right place. Therefore, this question should be preserved, but left marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

While searching more about line feed and text files I found a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks) here in the *superuser* community that explained what is happening.

The problem is not de *prompt*, is the *Notepad* from *Windows* (*in my case Windows 10, in the case of the author of the other question Windows 7*) that don't recoginize this type of *line feed*, quoting @Paul who answered the question I'm talking about:

> Notepad only recognises CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a), whereas other sources might use CR only, or LF only.

Now I recommend using as first text editor the *WordPad* or *NotePad++* that work normally.

In the *Notepad*:

[image: Notepad]

In *Notepad++* and *WordPad*:

[image: NotePad++]
[image: WordPad]

Other possible solution is to copy the text from the *Notepad*, pasting in the *Notepad++*, *WordPad*, *Microsoft Word* or any text editor that recognize this type of line break, and than copying it back.

For more information go to the question ["Notepad ignoring linebreaks"](https://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks).

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you're generating wrong line breaks. You program outputs Unix line breaks (only one "Line Feed"/LF character, ASCII code 10, "\n" in Java) while DOS and Windows use CR/LF (two characters, one "Carriage Return", ASCII code 13, escape sequence "\r" and one LF character).

Refer to the following question to learn how to use the correct newline characters for your operating system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character